# Can a relationship link three or more entities?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have an entity `employees` with six attributes: `employee_number` (unique key), `first_name`, `last_name`, `address`, `phone_number`, and `hire_date`. However, there are two types of employees: "Service Technicians" and "Sales Associates".

Each distinct type of employee has "job specific" attributes. Service technicians have `model_expertise` and `pager_number` attributes, and Sales associates have `commission` and `salary` attributes.

I'm not sure how to represent this in an ER diagram. I have an `employees` entity with the attributes listed, is it possible to have a relationship from `employees` to both `technicians` and `associates`? A relationship like `is_type`: can a relationship link one entity to two entities like this?

If not, how else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a classic subtype/supertype relationship. The original ER notation had no specific symbols for this situation, though one could represent subtypes as weak entities without a weak key. A number of extensions to the ER model were developed to address this. Here's one example:

[image: EER subtype example]

The `d` in the circle indicates disjoint subtypes, meaning an `Employee` can be either a `Technician` or an `Associate`, but not both. The other option is `o` for overlapping.

However, don't confuse your supertype/subtype relationships with a 3-way relationship. Rather, it's better viewed as 2 binary relationships, with disjointness being a mutual constraint. True 3-way (and higher) relationships (e.g. a many-to-many-to-many association among suppliers, parts and regions) are certainly possible in ER diagrams. It's one of the features that distinguish the ER model from the older network data model.